# Can Google Music Manager be launched at startup?

Tags: 13.04, startup, startup-applications, google-musicmanager

I would like Google Music Manager to launch **at startup**. I cannot find a way to accomplish this. Anyone have help?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the desktop environment you are using.

### Unity

In the dash, search for "Startup Applications"

### Gnome

System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications

### XFCE

Menu -> Settings Manager -> System | Session and Startup -> Application Autostart

Answer (score 1):

In the command field browse to File System -> opt -> google -> musicmanager -> google-musicmanager. Populating the field manually does not seem to work, so important to browse to location. (This works under GNOME fallback.)

Answer (score 0):

yeah just add it into the atartup application list!

you should know the start cmd for that application!

[image: Add Startup Program]

Comment: When I try to launch `google-musicmanager` in cli, I get an error `log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (root).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.` Won't that fault the launch at startup?